# OPA HTTP self referential PUT request times out

Tags: open-policy-agent

I have two policies in a `main` package which call the same instance (the locally running OPA server) like this:

```
package main

get[response] {
    response := http.send({
        "method" : "GET",
        "url": "http://localhost:8181/v1/data/example"
    })
}

put[response] {
    response := http.send({
        "method" : "PUT",
        "url": "http://localhost:8181/v1/data/example",
        "body": { "example": true }
    })
}
```

I run my OPA server like this:

```
opa run -w -s main.rego --log-level debug --log-format text
```

When I curl the `get` policy I get a 200 response:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8181/v0/data/main/get
[{"body":{},"raw_body":"{}","status":"200 OK","status_code":200}]
```

However, when I curl the put policy it times out after 5 seconds:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8181/v0/data/main/put
{
  "code": "internal_error",
  "message": "error(s) occurred while evaluating query",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "eval_builtin_error",
      "message": "http.send: Put http://localhost:8181/v1/data/example: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)",
      "location": {
        "file": "main.rego",
        "row": 11,
        "col": 14
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening for `PUT` and not `GET` requests against the OPA instance?

Meanwhile a comparable curl works fine:

```
curl -X PUT -d "{}" http://localhost:8181/v1/data/example
```

I'm aware this is a strange/bad 'use case' but I'm asking out of curiosity in an attempt to better understand what's going on in the rego http functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA currently supports multiple concurrent read transactions (e.g., policy queries) and one concurrent write transaction (e.g., updating data). However, when the write transaction commits, OPA waits until readers have finished.

Since you are executing a write operation from inside a policy query, the commit for the write operation blocks. This is why you see the timeout w/ the `put` rule. You do not see a timeout with the `get` rule because there are no write transactions (so nothing blocks.)

This is an implementation detail of OPA. In theory OPA could support multiple concurrent readers and writers and in that case you could modify data from inside a policy query. It's just not a high-priority feature.

That said, we **do not** recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks Torin for the prompt response. Would I be right in saying the read/write 'classification' of a transaction comes from the http verb? (I guess I previously had a webhook request against the v0 data API as a read in my mind)

Comment: PUT, PATCH, and DELETE on /data are writes that modify JSON data
PUT, DELETE on /policies are writes that modify policies

The other verbs are reads--even POST on /data is a read, it's how you execute a policy query with JSON inputs.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still a little confused. If the POST against v0/data is a read, then when the policy makes a PUT request against the same instance; would that not be just a single ongoing write? (and so wouldn't cause the timeout?)

Comment: Yes, there is only a single writer (i.e., the PUT request) however the writes cannot be committed until the reader (i.e., the POST request) finishes. It's like a single thread acquiring a read lock on a rw mutex and then trying to acquire a write lock on the same mutex without releasing the read lock.

Comment: Right - gotcha! Thanks for answer and clarification :)